# Add "symbol" field to Java class

Tags: java, java-annotations

I have a library, I have to tag a class with certain field dynamically (code generation) and I don't want the meta-data field names I generate to clash with user-defined field names.

Using JavaScript, we can use [ES6 Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) to do this. We can create getters/setters and retrieve fields using Symbols and in this way prevent name-clashing.

So using JS, it might look like:

```
export class Foo {

  static libraryDefinedField = Symbol('lib.defined')

  userDefinedField = 'whatev';

  setLibraryDefinedField(v){
    this[Foo.libraryDefinedField] = v;
  }

  getLibraryDefinedField(v){
    return this[Foo.libraryDefinedField];
  }

}
```

is there a way to do this with Java somehow - create *instance or static* fields on a class that won't conflict with user-defined fields?

*Note* that using JS, if there were user-generated *static* field properties and we wanted to prevent nameclashing, we might do this:

```
// put the symbol outside the class, so even static properties won't conflict
const libraryDefinedField = Symbol('lib.defined');

export class Foo {

  userDefinedField = 'whatev';

  setLibraryDefinedField(v){
    this[libraryDefinedField] = v;
  }

  getLibraryDefinedField(v){
    return this[libraryDefinedField];
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with metadata fields and user defined fields? Java is not a script language and users, whoever they are in this context, can’t just define fields. Besides java has scope, a field in one class doesn’t clash with a field in another class even if they have the same name.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think you missed the fact that this question is about code generation - users may define any number of fields.

Answer (score 1):

Java has no notion of symbols the way ES6 has.

If you simply want to "tag" a class, why not consider making the class implement an (possibly empty) interface? Class and interface names are unique.

Comment: Yeah I just need a unique name that is very unlikely or impossible to clash with a user-named / user-defined field